# Python - Can I import variables from another file as class variables?

Tags: python

I am trying to find a way to import variables ( dicts) from a file, which will be used inside as class , as class variables. Since I can't use **from myVarFile import *** inside a class, only at the module level, how would I import them as class variables

eg

```
from myVarFile import *


class myClass():

    #class variables here
    #should be the data from imported files
    print someImportedVariable

    def __init__(self):
        #init here

    def someClassFunction(self):
       #needs to access class variables
       self.someImportedVariable
```

As a test I have tried assigning 'global' to all the variables in myVarFile, and adding global variable names inside the class, this works at the class level. But I cannot get any methods to work at all, eg

```
class myClass():

    #class variables here
    #should be the data from imported files
    global someImportedVariable
    print someImportedVariable
    #this works

    def __init__(self):
        #init here

    def someClassFunction(self):
       #needs to access class variables
       self.someImportedVariable
       #this does not
```

I wanted to avoid having to globally declare all the variables in each class method, that seems wrong.

Do methods inherit the class variables if they are globally declared from an imported file ?

Comment: Are you sure you need that object to be a class attribute? `someImportedVariable` doesn't need to be declared a global if all you do is *read the value*. So `def someClassFunction(self): print someImportedVariable` works without further declaration.

Comment: Yes , in my case I only need to read the values from the myVarFile contents . Inside the myVarFile is simply lists of strings, and dicts. There are no methods or classes in there

Answer (score 1):

You can always *add* attributes to a class outside of the class body:

```
from module import *

class Bar:
    pass

Bar.foo = foo
```

or you could just import the name without the `*` syntax:

```
class Bar:
    from module import foo
```

Importing an object is basically an assignment; `import name` or `from module import name` sets `name` in the current namespace.

If you *must* take all the names from another module and put them in a class, consider *putting the class in that module*. At the very least, you can put a base class in the module that has all those names you want as attributes, and your new class can inherit it.

So, in the base module:

```
class BaseName:
    attribute1 = ...
    attribute2 = ...
```

That's just one indentation level added to what you have now, then in your other module:

```
from base_module import BaseName

class DerivedClass(BaseName):
    def method(self):
        # do something with self.attribute1, self.attribute2, etc.
```

If that's not an option, copy the namespace:

```
import module

class Bar:
    pass

# from module import * takes the names listed in module.__all__, or if that's
# missing, all names in the namespace that do not start with an underscore
_mod_namespace = vars(module)
_names = _mod_namespace.get('__all__', (n for n in _mod_namespace if n[:1] != '_'))
for _name in _names:
    setattr(Bar, _name, _mod_namespace[_name])
del _mod_namespace, _name, _names
```

Demo:

```
>>> from string import ascii_letters
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
...
>>> Foo.ascii_letters = ascii_letters
>>> Foo.ascii_letters
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> class Bar:
...     from string import digits
...
>>> Bar.digits
'0123456789'
>>> import string
>>> string.__all__
['ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'whitespace', 'Formatter', 'Template']
>>> class Bar:
...     pass
...
>>> before = set(dir(Bar))
>>> _mod_namespace = vars(string)
>>> _names = _mod_namespace.get('__all__', (n for n in _mod_namespace if n[:1] != '_'))
>>> for _name in _names:
...     setattr(Bar, _name, _mod_namespace[_name])
...
>>> [name for name in dir(Bar) if name not in before]
['Formatter', 'Template', 'ascii_letters', 'ascii_lowercase', 'ascii_uppercase', 'capwords', 'digits', 'hexdigits', 'octdigits', 'printable', 'punctuation', 'whitespace']
>>> Bar.hexdigits
'0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
>>> Bar.punctuation
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

*However*, if all you need to do is 'read' the value from your methods, you could just reference globals, you don't *have* to make such objects class attributes. *Just remove the `self.` prefix* from such names, and your code will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks . I got en error whilst trying this  inside my class, I had assumed I could only use ‘from Foo import *’ at the module level. I do need to be able to wildcard * , as the contents of the myVarFile are a set of variables, which could change . So I cannot explicitly import what I want

Comment: @blam why do you want to do that? Why not just put the class in the other module? You can copy across names from a module object (dynamically) but that’s not a very good way of organising your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure!

If you have a file *source.py* with a class like such:

```
class Animals:
   dogs = ['ralph', 'alex']
```

and another file *import_test.py*, you can do this:

```
class AnimalsTester: 
    from source import Animals

    print Animals.dogs

print AnimalsTester.Animals.dogs
```

Just make sure they are on the same directory level to keep it simple

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking. They want to import an object then make that imported object a class attribute.

Comment: whoops! I was missing a line. I believe I match the requirements. I am importing the Animals class as an object from another file for a class in the corresponding file to use.

Comment: Sure, you can add a class around it, but why then muddle the story with that `Animals` class? Or explain why you use `from ... import Animals` and how that relates to the question?

Comment: Fair point. The whole class import might seem like overkill, but in my mind I like separating constants I am importing. For example, there could be a separate class in source.py called Toys which would have structures for different types of toys for animals. This main AnimalsTesters class would then also be able to import that structure and do some processing on it for each animal or something.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case the source file myVarFile, is a set of dicts and string arrays. I need to simply import * all of them , I don’t need to import classes, nor can be explicit about what I’m importing

Answer (score 0):

In the end I’ve used the following :

inside the myVarFile.py

```
someDict = {some contents}
someVar = 'test'
```

inside the main.py

```
import myVarFile
class someClass ():
   def someMethod ():
          print myVarFile.someDict
```

So I avoid having to use class objects at all, and simply prefix the variable with the imported module name . This is clean as I can debug which module the variable is from, and avoid namespace clashes ( especially if I had multiple data modules to import )